# Sectioning command in between of \section and \subsection

Tags: macros, sectioning

In a book that I'm translating, there is a special kind of title that has the font size in between of that of `\section` and `\subsection`. This kind of title is never numbered, and is used for dividing a long section into different parts and providing description to each one.

At first I defined the unnumbered `\section*` to look like this. However, later I noticed that there is a interlude chapter in which everything is unnumbered and thus I have to reserve this `\section*` for unnumbered normal sections.

Currently I don't have any better idea than defining a new command, possibly with the name `\sectionsub`, that looks like the following:

```
\RequirePackage { relsize }
\NewDocumentCommand \sectionsub { m }
  {
    \medskip
    \group_begin:
    \noindent
    \relscale { 1.08 }
    \scshape
    #1
    \group_end:
    \par \smallskip
  }
```

However, this looks quite inelegant and unreliable to me. For example, I cannot set the spacing around it with `\titlespacing` from `titlesec`, which seems to me is better than using `\medskip` and `\smallskip`. Also, the use of `\par` here makes its behavior depend on the `\parskip`.

Do you have experience on dealing with this kind of title? And if I have to define new command for it, how can I reliably define it in the fashion of the usual `\section`, and maybe can hopefully compatible with tools like `titlesec`?

*I'm using `book` as the base class.*

Comment: What about defining subsection to be level 3, then define the "intermediate" one to be unnumbered level 2?

Comment: @user202729 It's just too weird to have `\section` to be numbered as `1.1` while `\subsubsection` as `1.1.1`, and I shall have to enable `\subsubsubsection` for `1.1.1.1`. Also, there would have to be too many modifications to the current document class, the style defined with `\titleformat`, the table of contents, and even the numbering of theorems... It would be much easier to simply define this as an extra sectional command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\titleclass` (package `titlesec`) is it possible to insert the new level `\sectionsub` between `\chapter` an `\section`.

```
\titleclass{⟨name⟩}{⟨class⟩}[⟨super-level-cmd⟩]
```

The "class" `straight`  is intended for titles in the middle of text.

Here the title format for `\sectionsub` was defined without a number.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\sectionsub}{straight}[\chapter] % added <<<<<<<<<<
\newcounter{sectionsub}% not used, just in case it is needed

\titleformat{\sectionsub}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\sectionsub}{0pt}{2.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % test numbered subsections

\begin{document}

\chapter{ONE}
1. \kant[1]

\sectionsub{Sec--Sub One}
2. \kant[2]

\section{Sec TWO}

3. \kant[3] 

\sectionsub{Sec--Sub Two}

4. \kant[4]

\subsection {Sub Sec One}

5. \kant[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually I've tried this approach a few hours before, but are facing some difficulties. Would you mind take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649841?