# Issues with titlesec's \titleclass

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, bookmarks, titletoc

Following the guideline in section *3.9. Creating new levels and changing the class* of the `titlesec` manual, I'm trying to create a new sectioning command `\sectionsub` under `\section`, to achieve what was asked in [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649797/194994). My current code is given below.

However, I'm facing two issues:

1. The numbering for `subsection` and `subsubsection` disappears.
2. There is a warning `bookmark level for unknown sectionsub defaults to 0`.

Regarding 1), of course `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` would work here, but the problem is that I'm not sure if `4` is the appropriate value. Regarding 2), `\let\toclevel@sectionsub\toclevel@section` works in the MWE given below, but for unknown reason, this does not work in the complete version of my document class (I tried to narrow down the problem for like an hour but it turns out to be fruitless).

How should I properly resolve these two issues?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

%% \sectionsub
\titleclass{\sectionsub}{straight}[\section]
\newcounter{sectionsub}
\renewcommand{\thesectionsub}{\Alph{sectionsub}}

\titleformat{\sectionsub}
  {\large\scshape}
  {\thesectionsub}
  {1em}
  {#1}
\titleformat{name=\sectionsub,numberless}
  {\large\scshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {#1}
\titlespacing{\sectionsub}{0pt}{.8\baselineskip}{.5\baselineskip}

\titlecontents{sectionsub}
  [4em]
  {\normalfont}
  {\contentslabel{1.75em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.75em}}
  {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}
\sectionsub{Test sectionsub}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`  to get numbered sub sections and sub sub sections in the book class. (Plus `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` to make them appear in the ToC)

(2) Load `hyperref` as the last package.

(3) with

```
\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@section{1}
\def\toclevel@sectionsub{2}
\def\toclevel@subsection{3}
\def\toclevel@subsubsection{4}
\makeatother
```

the warning disappears  and the `\sectionsub` is in the right place (after section and before subsection).

[image: a]

Comment: Thank you! One quick question: if I'm using class `article` instead of `book`, should I change the `1` in `\def\toclevel@sectionsub{1}` to `0` to make it the same level with `section`?

Comment: Also, regarding your 2), it seems from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113007 that the order of `hyperref` and `bookmark` doesn't really matter, one just needs to be careful about option clash.

Comment: (1) I do not see any difference of the output between book and article. (2) sometimes one forgets and adds new packages after hyperref. (there are exceptions)  It works better for me to follow a general rule. Thank you for your feedback!